# Pulling summary report for monitoring using reporting task in NiFi

Tags: api, microservices, apache-nifi

Working on a piece of the project where a report needs to be generated with all the flow details(memory used, number of records processed, Processes ran successful, failed, etc). Most of the details are present on the Summary tab, but the requirement is to have separate reports.

Can any one help me with solution/steps/examples/screens/videos.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

Every underlying behavior of the UX/UI that Apache NiFi provides is also accessible through [an API](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html) (in fact, the UI calls the API to perform each of these tasks). So you can invoke the `GET /system-diagnostics` API to return that information in JSON form, and then parse this data and present it in whatever form you like.

Comment: c I have the API from which I can get system diagnostics  and other details. However requirement is to pass this data to bulletin . Let me know if I can post it on Nifi Bulletin

Comment: Any component (processor, controller service, reporting task, etc.) running in NiFi can generate bulletins, but you cannot generate bulletins externally and arbitrarily post them using the API.